# Astronomy application

Tags: astronomy

I am trying to build an astronomy application where I should display the stars at and near zenith for a given latitude, longitude and time.

I am aware of the basics of Positional astronomy, what is puzzling me is to create database out of huge set of data!

My Queries are:

1. Which catalogue to prerfer? Like Hipparcos catalogue or Henry Draper? What are its advantages and disadvantages?
2. What fields are required? I have identified some, but what else should be added and why? Fields identified by me: Star name, Some Unique star ID, RA, Dec, Magnitude,Color of the star.
3. I tried to figure out from which table to fetch the **Common Star name** from the Hipparcos catalogue without any luck: http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/cgi-bin/VizieR-2?-source=I/239. I couldnt find in any of the tables.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Are you going to include planetary positions if in the field of view? If so, I would recommend ''Astronomical Algorithms'' by Jean Meeus, pub. Willman-Bell, 1991.

Comment: No pavium, at least as of now we are not planning for planetary positions. Where can I get common star names from, any idea?

Comment: @Raj It is quite a bit of time I downloaded any astro data so there may be something newer and better than in my answer. if you already have found something better please share.

Answer (score 4):

1. **I prefer BSC and Hipparcos catalogs**

   **BSC** is for naked eye apps (Bright Star Catalog up to `6.5 mag`). It is free and not too big to handle (`9110` stars)...

   **Hipparcos** is for astro apps (up to `12.5 mag`) and is also with manageable size (`118322` stars). It also contains **paralaxes** which means you can obtain **3D** position data which is cool for **stereo 3D** imaging. The original file size in ASCII format is `12.3 MB`. I compile it to these binary forms:

   ```
   (rec,dec,distance,RGB) 32bit -> 2.364MB
   (x,y,z,RGB) 32bit -> 2.364MB
   ```

   Which is small/fast enough for storing in memory and direct rendering.
2. **what fields to use**

   Absolute minimum to decode/use are: **RA,DE,Vmag,**[B-V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214). For more precision add also motions **pmRA,pmDE**. If you want **3D** add paralax **Plx** but also check if its error is not too high **e_Plx**. Also sometimes you need the ID of star in catalog **HIP** for example for star constellations mesh
3. **star names tables**

   They usually refers to **BSC** by ID of star but [here](http://ieti.org/articles/crossref.pdf) for example are more catalogs cross-reference with **Hipparcos** included.

Comment: I have used Hipparcos, but its been long time. I will add the details once I go through the project again. Thanks for your inputs.