# How to Linearise an Input Image before applying Color Correction?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors, camera

I'm doing color correction on Raw images taken from Camera directly. I want to make my Camera reproduce same colors as my Target camera.

Here are the steps I'm following:

1. Take Target Color values by Capturing a Macbeth Color chart by using Target Camera & Take set of 24 Color Palette's.
2. Take the Input Color Values by Capturing the same Macbeth Color chart by using Reference Camera & Take set of 24 Color Palette's.

Now if i Compute Color correction directly at this stage, all the White colors are appearing Rose or Not correct.

**So I'm applying Gamma correction as follows:**

1. Split the Three channels. For each Color find the Gamma for that color palette by using this formula.

   float Gamma_R = log10(Target_R/255.0))/(log10(Input_R/255.0);

**Error Cases:1**

If the Input_Channel Value == 255 make it as 254

If the Input_Channel Value == 0 make it as 1

If gamma_Channel > 3 or gamma_Channel < 0.2 make gamma_Channel as 1.

- Average the Values of Gamma_R for all 24 colors & make this as a
  gamma of that channel.
- Apply Gamma for Each channel using the Gamma computed for Each channel using the formula.

  Corrected_R = 255 * (Input_R/255)^(1/Gamma_R)

**My Problem:**

- How to make sure the Gamma Values that I've computed are correct at this stage? Also correct me if I'm doing it wrong.
- What to do when the Following Error case: 1 happens?
- After applying Gamma correction & Color Correction using 3x3 Matrix (Assume I'm doing that correctly) still the colors are not reproduced correctly.
- If i encode the gamma by using same Gamma Values from Previous stage using this formula, again the Colors are not reproduced correctly.

  Corrected_R = 255 * (Input_R/255)^(Gamma_R)
- So do i need to compute the Gamma again from the Color corrected output?

Any suggestion or References is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without detracting from Spektre's answer, note that good results can be obtained with the right approximations, and the first I'd try is a linear one. A few notes:

1. Your mention of a "gamma" seems to be confusing two very different things: (a) the "gamma expansion" that may or may not have been applied to the linear sensor values post digital conversion, and (b) a power law curve that you may want to use to match color spaces. Here we will concentrate on (a). For example, if you know that your sensor is recording at, say, 10 or 12 bits per physical (bayer pattern) pixel, but the camera yields images at 8 bits per channel after color mosaicing, there will usually be a nonlinear (usally power-law) expansion step applied before color mosaicing, to match human eye response to intensity (humans are less sensitive at low intensity values, so more bits should be allocated to the higher end of the intensity range). This is the same idea (but a different application) as the old "gamma compression" transform used when displaying on a CRT monitor.
2. The above point implies that, if you suspect that such a gamma expansion has been applied to your image's luma values, you should invert it in order to get (approximately) luma-linear values before attempting any colorspace matching. This is particularly important if you plan to use a linear matching method, as I am going to suggest next.
3. Once you have both your input and your reference (target) images in linear luma space, you can try a linear match between them using the image of your Macbeth color chart. To do so, you first must represent your colors in a (mathematical) linear space as well, e.g. "CIELAB". Look up on Wikipedia the conversion equations from RGB to CIELAB. They require you to specify a color temperature, and this should be the same (or close to) the one had when capturing the colorchart images (e.g. daylight ~= 6500K).
4. Input and reference CIELAB values can then be linearly matched. This means estimating a 3x3 color transformation Q such that reference_lab ~= Q * input_lab, for all reference and input color values. To compute the estimate you can select on both images the pixels upon the colored patches of the Macbeth chart (usually a few hundreds in each patch), and then average them to get a single value per patch in each image. These are your input-output values upon which you estimate Q. The estimation uses a standard linear least-squares algorithm (e.g. RQ or SVD factorization of the design matrix implied by the matching problem).
5. As for practicalities, be mindful of outliers when matching - outliers will surely make nonsense of any nonrobust linear algo. In particular, make sure the pixels you select for matching are well inside the images of each colored patch to avoid mixing at the patch borders. Also, be mindful to keep the chart oriented approximately in the same way w.r.t. both cameras, that the illumination be as uniform as possible across it.

With a little care, a linear approximation should give you a pretty close match. Remember that the estimated transformation is valid only in linear CIELAB color space, so to apply to natural (non-chart) images you'll have to follow the whole transform chain: undo gamma expansion of the intensity => conversion to Lab => apply Q => back-conversion to RGB => gamma compression to go back to 8bpp.

A linear approximation is also usually a good starting point for a nonlinear refinement, where you try to estimate a "small", usually polynomial, correction to the Q-transformed values to improve the visual appearance of the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to approach this a bit differently

check if your cameras use the same wavelength bands. If not then you are in big trouble. this:

- [multi band rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575362/2521214)

may shine some light to it. You need to handle bands as continuous spectra so handle one camera colors as control points for curve and get the points for bands of the second camera. But for 3 bands only (usual case for standard cameras) is this not very precise. Only after this you can apply the following

if the bands are the same or very close then do this:

1. **obtain transfer function for each band of each camera**

   it will be in form:

   ```
   R'=r0+r1*R+r2*R*R+...
   ```

   where `R'` is red band real intensity. `R` is the intensity returned by camera

   the `r0,r1,..` are transfere function constant like bias,brightness,gamma,...

   this can be obtained from color gradients only. Do not use palette use band color gradients instead
2. **when you look at the polynomials they are curves**

   so compute real intensity from your camera and find point on curve which return the same intensity on your second camera and that is the resulting output for each band ...

   You can use bin search for this ... or compute inverse polynomial

Comment: Sounds like I'm looking at a much bigger problem :(

Comment: @BalajiR yep ... the bands parameters can be usually obtained from camera  chip datasheed... measure them is insaine withouth pretty expensive lab equiptiment I can only dream of ...

Answer (score 1):

I have a small suggestion to the Gamma Correction:

Instead of averaging the gammas you are obtaining, do a small minization process like the follow:
find the **Gamma** that minimize `|ref-F(qry,**Gamma**)|` ; ref is the first camera image and qry is the second camera image.
Regards

Comment: Thank you @Humam I'm now referring this eq for Gamma Calculation. http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?ColorCalculator.html  Hope you will also find this like useful!