# How to create color images from u,g,r,i band images?

Tags: numpy, astropy, astronomy

Does anyone know an algorithm that takes multidimensional numpy arrays which contain 4-channel (u,g,r,i) band images and plots them in color? The method found in astropy only deals with RGB 3 channel data.

Comment: see [Multi-Band Image raster to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575362/2521214)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-Band Image raster to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560045/multi-band-image-raster-to-rgb)