# how to find RGB values and COLOR TEMPERATURE using android camera?

Tags: android, colors, android-camera, rgb

i want to find the RGB values of the camera scene as shown in the image below ..please can anyone guide me on how to implement the following scenario using android stock camera application.

[image]

Comment: see [Star B-V color index to apparent RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214)