# Colormap that is commonly used for dark matter simulations

Tags: colors, colormap, astronomy

I am wondering what colormap all the astro people are using to simulate dark matter. 
It always looks black-violett-orangish like here and I really like it.

https://www.google.com/search?q=+dark+matter+simulation&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiq9sWhgLnoAhUQNxoKHTgXANUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=+dark+matter+simulation&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgQIABAYUKJuWKJuYP9waABwAHgAgAFhiAFhkgEBMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=lxN9XurOGpDuaLiugKgN&bih=635&biw=1366&client=firefox-b-d

Any idea what values are used there or is it a specific colormap from matplotlib or something?

Comment: for **matter** and **stars** the  BV coeficients are used they representing color related to the black body at some temperature ... see [Star B-V color index to apparent RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214) ... its computed from black body spectra computed by plank equations and then converted to RGB by integrating the X,Y,Z curves (human color perception) ... **dark matter** is invisible so all the colors are just fiction and any custom gradient scale can be used

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know any clormap can be used and the colors do not map to any visible or whatever wavelength of the spectra. I just wanted to know the name of the map that is often used in that field because I like the colors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be 'Viridis' colormap.